# Escape forward slash in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have dozens of routes like the following list

```
Route::group([
    'where' => ['aNumber' => '.*'],
], function () {
    Route::get('air/{aNumber}/tools', 'AirController@tools');
    Route::post('air/{aNumber}/handled', 'AirController@handled');
    Route::post('air/{aNumber}/notHandled', 'AirController@notHandled');
    Route::get('air/{aNumber}/act', 'AirController@act');
    Route::post('air/{aNumber}/sendAct', 'AirController@sendAct');
    Route::get('air/{aNumber}', 'AirController@show');
});
```

the `{anumber}` parameter could be like these `23-349493/4` While this kind of parameter will produce some conflicts with other routes, So for example if we are going to call `air/28-23422/sendAct` then instead of calling `@sendAct` route, it'll call `@show`.

because laravel thinks that `/sendAct` is part of the parameter. Well, I can fix this problem by adding more where not(Regex) on each of the routes and define the logic that every route should follow, But do you have a better solution for this problem?

Comment: can you add `aNumber` what kind of data you want to accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are wrong, `Laravel` will choose `show` since `air/28-23422/sendAct` won't hit `sendAct`  because `sendAct` has as supposed method `POST`, and not `GET`.
Instead of:

```
Route::post('air/{aNumber}/sendAct', 'AirController@sendAct');
```

try writing

```
Route::get('air/{aNumber}/sendAct', 'AirController@sendAct');
//     ^^^
```

Or use `^[^\/]*` as where clause of the group for `aNumber`

Comment: You are right, It's working fine. I have tried tools and it's not hitting the @show.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab so now it's working? in case, feel free to mark the answer as correct